# Extract URL parameter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a URL parameter from the following URL

```
http://localhost:4200/#/candidate/login/?corporateid=66d8c83c-841a-42e8-945c-beb8c1af25ef&userid=cb2147ed-bd42-4b9f-82d4-0dcef861e24d&token=CfDJ8Ie7+UQ8GQRBtQNOMB6ytQXk0OvqW+/l9W1yh3gCLQw7Sa606eaQtWAC472uUrsUnMQtt69R4gF7f6aab/lIdToo9AfiwtJ7wlsdYnomPpo1OgOaIUZZVBtEaBxRfuJin/Rl+WO+AnvHAn6v4Sf2yO+2gkNotCw0yLsfgzKYOwOciVRDHWY5mNktbGsRCb96kbnxd6VyW02Vs7szuSBG4Ow5fFdtvVUkQDj+ne4HZQAyvts8pNOOkNT/g+cCbOO/wA==
```

The parameter value that I need is the userid but I seem to be getting a null.

Here is my code

```
location = window.location;
urlHref = location.href;
urlConvert = new URL(this.urlHref);

if (location.toString().includes('userid')) {
  this.userId = this.urlConvert.searchParams.get("userid");
  console.log(this.userId);    
} else {
  this.userId = 'user';
  console.log('gets user not candidate');
}
```

Comment: Try: `Route.params`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I still get the same result

Comment: Cannot find `userid` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and its [`.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) function to get the query string value.

```js
const str = 'http://localhost:4200/#/candidate/login/?corporateid=66d8c83c-841a-42e8-945c-beb8c1af25ef&userid=cb2147ed-bd42-4b9f-82d4-0dcef861e24d&token=CfDJ8Ie7+UQ8GQRBtQNOMB6ytQXk0OvqW+/l9W1yh3gCLQw7Sa606eaQtWAC472uUrsUnMQtt69R4gF7f6aab/lIdToo9AfiwtJ7wlsdYnomPpo1OgOaIUZZVBtEaBxRfuJin/Rl+WO+AnvHAn6v4Sf2yO+2gkNotCw0yLsfgzKYOwOciVRDHWY5mNktbGsRCb96kbnxd6VyW02Vs7szuSBG4Ow5fFdtvVUkQDj+ne4HZQAyvts8pNOOkNT/g+cCbOO/wA==';
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(str);
const userId = urlParams.get('userid') || '';

console.log(userId);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try in your destination Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: `
  <h1>A</h1>
  <p> params: {{params | json}}</p>
  <p> query params: {{queryParams | json}}</p>
  <p> url: {{url}}</p>
  <p> full url: {{fullUrl}}</p>`
})
export class AComponent  {
  params;
  queryParams;
  url;
  fullUrl;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.params = this.route.snapshot.params;
    this.queryParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
    this.url = this.route.snapshot.url.join('');
    this.fullUrl = this.router.url;  
  }
}
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-get-parameter-vr18rt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActivatedRoute` to get your route params. In addition, it is possible to get always fresh parameters by using `queryParamMap`. Because `queryParamMap` returns  `Observable<ParamMap>`:

```
constructor( 
        private route: ActivatedRoute
)

this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
    let userId = params.get('userId ');
});
```